# In swift, how to convert a struct with a variable of a 2D dictionary to a saved data?

Tags: swift, dictionary, core-data

I have a struct:

```
struct Personne {let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    var nom: String = ""
    var prenom: String = ""
    var age: Int = 18
    var email: String = ""
    var motDePass: String = ""
    var genre: Genre = .Femme
   enum Genre {
    case Homme, Femme, Autre}
  
  var historique: [Date: [[AlimentObject]]] = [Date(): [[], [], [], [], [], []]]

   //etc ...
}
```

and AlimentObject struct:

```
struct AlimentObject : Equatable {
    
        var nomAliment = ""
        var uuid = UUID().uuidString
        var poids : Float = 100
        var calories : Float = 0
        var proteines : Float = 0
        var lipides : Float = 0
        var glucides : Float = 0
}
```

I need to convert everything in CoreData

I have already created an NSManagedObject object of the class named AlimentObject, and another of the class Personne. The original classes will be deleted in the end, and the NSManagedObject will take their places.

The question is, how to put the variable "historique" in a saved data in order to load it, and save it when needed?

PS:
@Leo here is the function that i put in the view did load of the very first view controller:

```
public func sauvegarderDonneesPersonnne() {
        do {
            let appSupport = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let appSupportDirectory = appSupport.appendingPathComponent(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, isDirectory: true)
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: appSupportDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = appSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Personne.json")

            let loadedData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            // decoding the data loaded
            let loadedPersonne: Personne = try loadedData.decodedObject()
            self.personne.shared = loadedPersonne
            print("loaded")
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

and here is the on in the save button:
it's a simple button, where the user saves his data when he tapped it

```
public func sauvegarderDonneesPersonnne() {
        do {
            let appSupport = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let appSupportDirectory = appSupport.appendingPathComponent(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, isDirectory: true)
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: appSupportDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = appSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Personne.json")
            // encoding
            let data = try personne.shared.data()
            // saving
            try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
            print("saved")
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not related to your question but you are initialising your dictionary with an empty key value pair `var historique: [Date: [[AlimentObject]]] = [:]`

Comment: @LeoDabus no at all, i need a dictionary with today date and 5 empty sections

Comment: Regarding storing a custom object in CoreData, make it a NSObject class instead of a structure, conform it to NSCoding and archive/unarchieve its data using NSKeyedArchiever/NSKeyedUnarchiever to encode/decode your custom class.

Comment: So you don't need a dictionary, you need a tuple. If you need more that a single date you can always use dictionary key based subscript with a default value. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript

Comment: could you help me please with Core Data? i didn't find any tutorial talking about  this type of problem, and all my application with it 50 view controllers is operating but without memory ...

Comment: Core Data is definitely something not easy to implement. It takes time. Have you considered just using Codable to persist your data?

Comment: @LeoDabus If you are talking about userDefault, i used it for simple variables, but definitly not for 12Mo of data

Comment: No I am suggesting to save your data directly to the application support directory as JSON

Comment: When saving it inside UserDefaults it needs to convert your data into base64 encoded data.

Comment: @LeoDabus How could i do that? is it possible to save the variable of "Personne" witch is my unique variable which need persistence. i navigate in all the 50 view controllers with it. and the dependency injection begins in the AppDelegate.

Comment: @LeoDabus How to convert this heavy instance of Person in a stored variable?

Comment: I can't post an answer right now but I will later if nobody answers your question. You can try the json approach if it doesn't work as expected you go for the NSCoding/CoreData approach.

Comment: @LeoDabus i think that nobody will answer my question. thank you a lot by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comments you can try first to encode your data using Codable protocol and write it to your application support directory:

This is how I would structure your data:

```
struct Personne: Codable {
    enum Genre: String, Codable { case homme, femme, autre }
    let uuid: String
    let nom: String
    let prenom: String
    let age: Int
    let email: String
    let motDePass: String
    let genre: Genre
    var historique: [Date: [[AlimentObject]]] = [:]
    init(uuid: String = UUID().uuidString, nom: String, prenom: String, age: Int, email: String, motDePass: String, genre: Genre, historique: [Date: [[AlimentObject]]]) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.nom = nom
        self.prenom = prenom
        self.age = age
        self.email = email
        self.motDePass = motDePass
        self.genre = genre
        self.historique = historique
    }
}
```

---

```
struct AlimentObject: Codable, Equatable {
    let uuid: String
    let nomAliment: String
    let poids: Float
    let calories: Float
    let proteines: Float
    let lipides: Float
    let glucides: Float
    init(uuid: String = UUID().uuidString, nomAliment: String, poids: Float, calories: Float, proteines: Float, lipides: Float, glucides: Float) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.nomAliment = nomAliment
        self.poids = poids
        self.calories = calories
        self.proteines = proteines
        self.lipides = lipides
        self.glucides = glucides
    }
}
```

---

---

Add those helpers to your project to make it easier to encode/decode your objects:

```
extension JSONEncoder {
    static let iso8601 = JSONEncoder(dateEncodingStrategy: .iso8601)
}
```

---

```
extension JSONEncoder {
    convenience init(dateEncodingStrategy: DateEncodingStrategy) {
        self.init()
        self.dateEncodingStrategy = dateEncodingStrategy
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Encodable {
    func data(using encoder: JSONEncoder = .iso8601) throws -> Data {
        try encoder.encode(self)
    }
    func json() throws -> String {
        try String(data: data(), encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    static let iso8601 = JSONDecoder(dateDecodingStrategy: .iso8601)
}
```

---

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    convenience init(dateDecodingStrategy: DateDecodingStrategy) {
        self.init()
        self.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Data {
    func decodedObject<T: Decodable>(using decoder: JSONDecoder = .iso8601) throws -> T {
        try decoder.decode(T.self, from: self)
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let personne: Personne = .init(nom: "nom",
                               prenom: "prenom",
                               age: 18,
                               email: "email",
                               motDePass: "motDePass",
                               genre: .femme,
                               historique:
[Date() :
    [
     [.init(nomAliment: "nomAlimentA", poids: 1.1, calories: 1.2, proteines: 1.3, lipides: 1.4, glucides: 1.5),
      .init(nomAliment: "nomAlimentB", poids: 2.2, calories: 2.3, proteines: 2.4, lipides: 2.5, glucides: 2.6)],
     [.init(nomAliment: "nomAlimentC", poids: 3.3, calories: 3.4, proteines: 3.5, lipides: 3.6, glucides: 3.7),
      .init(nomAliment: "nomAlimentD", poids: 4.4, calories: 4.5, proteines: 4.6, lipides: 4.7, glucides: 4.8)]
    ]
])

do {
    let appSupport = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let appSupportDirectory = appSupport.appendingPathComponent(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "companyName", isDirectory: true)
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: appSupportDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    let fileURL = appSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Personne.json")
    // encoding
    let data = try personne.data()
    // saving
    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
    // loading
    let loadedData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    // decoding the data loaded
    let loadedPersonne: Personne = loadedData.decodedObject()
    print("loadedPersonne", loadedPersonne)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print:

> loadedPersonne Personne(uuid: "9E6A65EB-8F94-4CCE-B4F8-60EA79EA4D02", nom: "nom", prenom: "prenom", age: 18, email: "email", motDePass: "motDePass", genre: Personne.Genre.femme, historique: [2020-11-16 21:45:22 +0000: [[AlimentObject(uuid: "2ED19F72-52BE-4A6C-BB23-3E436BE3DEB3", nomAliment: "nomAlimentA", poids: 1.1, calories: 1.2, proteines: 1.3, lipides: 1.4, glucides: 1.5), AlimentObject(uuid: "F73812E8-BD3F-4BC3-A734-4EA9ECDEE130", nomAliment: "nomAlimentB", poids: 2.2, calories: 2.3, proteines: 2.4, lipides: 2.5, glucides: 2.6)], [AlimentObject(uuid: "C73A5162-A63E-44A3-972A-4F368385277D", nomAliment: "nomAlimentC", poids: 3.3, calories: 3.4, proteines: 3.5, lipides: 3.6, glucides: 3.7), AlimentObject(uuid: "BA3091D5-D54D-4F31-BFA0-8E74CC004F46", nomAliment: "nomAlimentD", poids: 4.4, calories: 4.5, proteines: 4.6, lipides: 4.7, glucides: 4.8)]]])

Comment: i think that you show me how to decode the instance of "person", but could you please show me how to encode it ?

Comment: It is not mandatory but I recommend (to be able to declare your properties as constants).

Comment: @Monica it is done at the same line that writes it to disk `let data = try personne.data()` check my last edit

Comment: i am a beginer. please tell me where do i have to put the do catch code? is it in the view controller where i have to save the date or else where ?

Comment: Whenever you call a method that throws you need to catch the error. You will probably need to load your person inside viewDidLoad. And always save it as soon as it changes

Comment: I understand. You gave me the method to load it. but what is the code to save it?

Comment: I gave you both. It is writing the data and then loading  the contents of the file and decoding it. `try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)` saves the file and `let loadedPersonne: Personne = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL).decodedObject()` loads it and decode

Comment: Do i have to replace the companyName with mine?

Comment: You can but it not really needed. You can also force unwrap the Bundle Identifier. `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!`

Comment: I think that it is going to work. but i need to know something important because i am a beginner: I have to put your do catch code in the function of saving, but what is the specific code for loading data in the first view did load of the first view controller ?

Comment: You will need this do try catch code on both of them. The only difference will be the last 4 lines. Use the first 2 for encoding/saving  and the last 2 for loading/decoding.

Comment: i understand now what you said. i am experimenting it. and it is working. but i takes 10 secondes to save. it's a good solution with a save button. but o can't use it everywhere of the app. what do you think?

Comment: 10s to save? How long does it take to load it? Are you sure you are updating the UI from the main thread?

Comment: i use the code like you said. i put do cach with load in the view did load of the first controller, and the same do catch but with save in the save button. because i have 15Mo to save. I am going to write your function in the two differents versions save/load in the end of my question

Comment: Do you know what I mean by update the UI from the main thread? It shouldn't be an issue considering there is no data being downloaded. what is `15Mo`?

Comment: excuse me Leo but i don't understand what you mean. i know what is main thread, but i don't know if i am doing well.
15Mo is a data transformed by the user. it's not the same in each manipulation

Comment: I don't think thats the issue but I can only be sure if you show your view controller code

Comment: ok i will put the function in the end of my question

Comment: i already put the variant of you function in the end of my function.
do i have to put the function in another thread? because 6 secondes each time is too much

Comment: You can also save it in the background. This will not block the main thread. `DispatchQueue.global().async {`
    // save your data here
    `DispatchQueue.main.async {`
       // update UI here if needed
    `}`
`}`

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooo much Leo. you can't understand how i was in trouble. just you can't. you just saved me. i am very gratefull. thank you. your solution works very well.i add a background thread to squeeze the 6 secondes of saving. it's just incredible