# Why my CustomType cannot conform to Decodable even I conformed it?

Tags: swift

I have a CustomType that conforms to Decodable, when I want use it as needed value for my function, Xcode complain that CustomType does not conform to Decodable! Should I explicitly make CustomType conformation happen, I also did it, but it did not solved the issue! What I am missing here?

Error:

> Type 'CustomType.Type' cannot conform to 'Decodable'

```
let stringOfJSON: String = """
{ "name": "SwiftPunk", "age": 35 }
"""

let dataOfJSON: Data? = stringOfJSON.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

---

```
struct CustomType: Decodable {
    
    enum Codingkeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, age
    }
    
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Codingkeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
    }
    
    
}
```

---

```
func decoderFunction<T: Decodable>(dataOfJSON: Data?, customType: T, decodedValue: (T) -> Void) {
    
    if let unwrappedDataOfJSON: Data = dataOfJSON {
        
        let dataJSONDecoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let value: T = try dataJSONDecoder.decode(T.self, from: unwrappedDataOfJSON)
            decodedValue(value)
        } catch {
            print("The Data could not be decoded!")
        }
    }
}
```

---

use case:

```
decoderFunction(dataOfJSON: dataOfJSON, customType: CustomType.self, decodedValue: { value in
 
})
```

Comment: Unrelated but with a standard implementation you get almost everything for free. The code of your struct can be reduced to `struct CustomType: Decodable { let name: String let age: Int}`. And you can also write much shorter `let dataOfJSON = Data(stringOfJSON.utf8)` (no optional)

Comment: @vadian: Thanks, for help. I just tried all I could before asking my question.

Comment: @vadian: Since you are more experienced, I have a side question as well, if you could help, I have a very bad feeling to defining an instance of JSONDecoder inside my function every time I use my function, and maybe I am going use it like 1000 times in app, I could define that instance outside of function to stop new creation but that looks ugly also, do we have a silver bullet for such a issues? What is best way or approach? Inside or outside?

Comment: There is no performance issue if you create a decoder without any key/date/data decoding strategies directly in the method.

Comment: @vadian: thanks, in case if my decoder is with key/date/data decoding strategies, I believe you are going to say outside of function would be better, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer to write an extension of `JSONDecoder` and add a static method returning the configured decoder. If you are going to use different decoders you could even add a parameter to the method.

Comment: @swiftPunk regarding creating only one decoder and avoiding racing conditions you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66372577/2303865)

Comment: @LeoDabus: I was hoping you help me also, thanks I will read it.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I read more about that Link, in that link you are creating a value type of a class. In my app or issue, I want get the most performance and stop doing repeating work or extra load to CPU. So I am going to make an extension for JSONDecoder and like vadian said making it static `static let decoder: JSONDecoder()`and I would access it like: `JSONDecoder.decoder`, So I think it will be okay. right?

Comment: As long as you don’t change its properties it is ok. That should be fine if you are the only one working on the code

Comment: @swiftPunk this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/64866249/2303865

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of the `customType` parameter is incorrect. It should be the *metatype* of `T` (`T.Type`), not `T`.

```
func decoderFunction<T: Decodable>(dataOfJSON: Data?, customType: T.Type, decodedValue: (T) -> Void) {
    ...
}
```

The method was expecting a value of type `T`, which should conform to `Decodable`, but you were giving it a value of type `CustomType.Type`, which doesn't conform to `Decodable` (but note that `CustomType` does).

Also note that you don't need the `customType` parameter at all. `T` can be inferred if you specify the type in the closure:

```
func decoderFunction<T: Decodable>(dataOfJSON: Data?, decodedValue: (T) -> Void) {
    ...
}

decoderFunction(dataOfJSON: dataOfJSON, decodedValue: { (value: CustomType) in
 
})
```

Comment: Kudos to you, this helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Change the function signature to:

```
func decoderFunction<T: Decodable>(
    dataOfJSON: Data?, 
    customType: T.Type, 
    decodedValue: (T) -> Void)
```

You want to pass in the type of `T` not a value of `T`

Answer (score 1):

As you apparently like to annotate types I would omit the type parameter completely and annotate the type in the closure of the caller function.

Further use the `Result` type to handle a potential error and pass the JSON string to the function rather than optional `Data`

```
let stringOfJSON: String = """
{ "name": "SwiftPunk", "age": 35 }
"""

struct CustomType: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

func decoderFunction<T: Decodable>(json: String, decodedValue: (Result<T,Error>) -> Void) {
    decodedValue(Result {
        try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    })
}
```

And call it

```
decoderFunction(json: stringOfJSON) { (result : Result<CustomType,Error>) in
    
    switch result {
        case .success(let value): print(value)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```